# Is it possible to use an swf file in android java programming?

Tags: java, android, flash

I just wanted to know is it possible to add a swf file to an android java application and control it like passing argument calling functions or so. I have used it in c# application before using shockwave flash object but I didn't manage to find something like this for android java application.

If it's possible then how?

any helps would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Flash is not natively supported by Android. It depends on the device customization. The HTC Desire had it native in 2009, on Android 2.1 and 2.2.

Comment: No I don't want to use it native. I just wanted to import it as an activeX to an android java application.

Comment: ... what? a dll? in Android? you must be joking...

Comment: No, but Android supports Adobe AIR, if it helps.

Comment: I don't want to use Air because it wont support all cpu range of mobile devices.